# How to fit Tooltip to screen for mobile responsiveness in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show Material UI [Tooltip](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#tooltip) fit to screen and screen width rather fit to the children element.

While in not mobile devices, Tooltip component is shown position absolute and place regarding the placement props.

But in mobile devices, I want to make Tooltip width full and also center the screen.

[image: ![enter image description here]

How to make this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I don't know how to use Popper component.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a minimum width via the tooltips `classes` [prop](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#props).

Like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  customWidth: {
    minWidth: "95vw",
  }
}))

export default function FullWidthTooltip() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Tooltip
      title="Full width"
      classes={{ tooltip: classes.customWidth }}
    >
      <Button variant="contained">Hover me</Button>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

You can view a demo on CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-fullwidthtooltip-ov29t?file=/src/components/FullWidthTooltip.js)